# Almost everywhere differentiable (composition)!

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function differentiable almost everywhere and $g$ a function defined by

$$g(t)=\arctan(f(t))$$

I read in a paper that $g$ is differentiable almost everywhere. Can someone tell me why $g$ is differentiable almost everywhere?

Comment: wherever $f$ has a derivative, we can have $g'(t)=\frac{f'(t)}{1+(f(t))^2}$. So only on a set of measure $0$, $g$ may not have a derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable at $t$, then (because $\arctan$ is differentiable at $f(t)$) by the chain rule $g$ is also differentiable at $t$. If we state this contrapositively, we have
\begin{align}
\{t\in \Bbb{R}| \, \, \text{$g$ not differentiable at $t$}\} \subseteq \{t\in \Bbb{R}| \, \, \text{$f$ not differentiable at $t$}\}
\end{align}
Since the set on the right has measure zero, so does the set on the left.